# PowerShell remote PC shutdown, single PC

Tags: powershell, shutdown

OU=_ is a private company name. I know it's restart, this is only for testing before it goes into the real hutdown process.

```
function Get-LastBootUpTime {            
param (
    $ComputerName
)
    $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName               
    [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)            
}

$Days = -0
$ShutdownDate = (Get-Date).adddays($days)

$ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=TEST-OU,OU=_,DC=_,DC=_' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name

$ComputerList | foreach {
    $Bootup = Get-LastBootUpTime -ComputerName $_

    Write-Host "$_ last booted: $Bootup"

    if ($ShutdownDate -gt $Bootup) {
        Write-Host "Rebooting Computer: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
        restart-Computer $Computer -Force
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No need to reboot: $_" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

I'm trying to shutdown all of the PCs in my company that run longer than 2 days. The script is kind of done, but it shows an error when it comes to the point:

```
restart-Computer $Computer -Force
```

If I type instead of $Computer, $ComputerList the script shuts down every PC in that OU, even if they didnt run longer than 2 days.
So it only takes one PC to run longer than 2 days to shut down the entire company, and that's not what I want.
How can I tell the script to only turn the PCs off, when they have already run more than 2 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$Computer` is not defined. You should use:

```
Restart-Computer $_ -Force
```

But the better approach would be to collect all of the computers that should restart in a variable and then restart them altogether. Would work much faster:

```
$toBeRestarted = $ComputerList | Where-Object { $ShutdownDate -gt (Get-LastBootUpTime -ComputerName $_) }
Restart-Computer $toBeRestarted -Force
```

You may add some more logging around if you like

Comment: I solved the Restart-Computer $_ -Force just now, I think it works. I didn't test it with time because the PCs I want to shutdown arent online long enough, but on Monday I will test it more thoroughly.

If it doesn't work I'm going to try your other solution, thank you.